# Xamarin- Image Resolution gets lower after removing Launch Storyboard property in the info.plist

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using the xamarin to code my project. Now i have an issue when i deploy to the IOS. I am intending to create a splash screen, i have put all the images into the universal icon, but in the end when i debug it the splash screen does not show the image i put. In this case, But google shows below resolution

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32951/ios-launch-images-not-showing-up

After deleting the launch story board parameter in the info.plist. The solution works but a new problem appears, after the splash screen is loaded, all the textbox and the label showed a bigger font and I bet the resolution droped since i left the launch story board empty, how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If the screen resolution is incorrect, then ios thinks your app is not targeted for the current device resolution, and scale it.

So make sure you set all the required launchscreen and app icons for your device.

Btw if you are using Visual Studio, it won't work. switch to Xamarin Studio Mac, delete all existing asset catalogs, and create a new one.

One it work with Xamarin Studio Mac, it will also work in Visual Studio. But never edit the assets catalogs with Visual Studio again.